# Azure Application Gateway support Open ID connect Authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have an azure web app , which has open id connect authentication configured with Azure AD 
For this , i had created a new app under **App Registrations** in Azure Active Directory and configured the Redirect URL as /signin-oidc . So when i try to login to the app service url , it first redirects to the redirect url and then to https://login.microsoftonline.com and passes the client id ,tenant etc details in the query string **and works perfectly fine**. So i can login with my azure ad user credentials

The Web Application is working perfectly fine with Open ID Connect with Azure AD.

When i front Azure Web App , with an Azure Application Gateway , it directly redirects to 
/signin-oidc and stops there . I tried redirect options also. 
Does Azure Application Gateway support -open id connect authentication with Azure AD. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , we can use application gateway with open id authentication. In my case, SSL certificate was missing and i got it working once added.

Answer (score 0):

Same scenario here, an App Service behind an Application Gateway. Here's what worked:

The `BuildRedirectUri` method in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler<>` builds the redirect URI concatenating, among other values, the `Resquest.Host` string. That's why the App Service host was being used instead of the Gateway's.

So, the following code snipped was added to the `Configure()` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
if (env.IsProduction())
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {                    
         context.Request.Host = new HostString("<gateway.host>");
         return next();
    });
}
```