# Azure Application Gateway Open ID Authentication RedirectUri

Tags: vb.net, azure, owin

In our payment scenario (ASP.Net MVC 5 web application VB.Net), the user might be redirected to the card issuer for further identification.
After completing the identification, the user is redirected back to our web application.
The action that is hit has the Authorize attribute.

Some times the request needs to be authorized again, and the request is taken to RedirectToIdentityProvider - here the ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri is correct, however the request is redirected to the application gateway and not the web application.

I have had a look at this SO question: [Azure Application Gateway support Open ID connect Authentication][1]
I'm not able to make comments due to my newbie status...
Can soneone please help me translate the C# snippet in above question to VB.net:

```
if (env.IsProduction())
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {                    
         context.Request.Host = new HostString("<gateway.host>");
         return next();
    });
}
```

The app.use part
[1]: [Azure Application Gateway support Open ID connect Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61850097/azure-application-gateway-support-open-id-connect-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

The problem originated in the Azure configuration